# issue with sql query to count by groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT s.username FROM `instagram_shop` s
INNER JOIN `instagram_shop_picture` p
ON s.id = p.shop_id
WHERE s.`deletedAt` IS NULL
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0
GROUP BY s.id
```

and I keep getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  'GROUP BY s.id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

What is the issue here?

Comment: Where are you typing the request PHPMyAdmin, SQL Server ... ?
Are you typing only one command or multiple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY` clause.

MySQL is very specific about the order of keywords/clauses in a SELECT statement

Reference: [**13.2.9 SELECT Syntax** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below one :
there is an syntax issue with your query, 
Having should follow after GROUP BY caluse.

Also the columns which you mention in your GROUP BY 
clause should be present in the SELECT list.

SELECT s.id,s.username FROM `instagram_shop` s
INNER JOIN `instagram_shop_picture` p
ON s.id = p.shop_id
WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL 
GROUP BY s.id,s.username 
HAVING COUNT(s.id) = 0
```

Comment: please add some description instead of just code so that person come to know what is the issue, like Spencer did.